# Generate database script using visual studio 2012

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

How can i generate database script (.sql file) from visual studio 2012. I do not have management studio.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific to get a helpful answer.  What script are you trying to generate? Just script the creation of a database?

Comment: SSMS Express is free.

Comment: i need database script with schema and data through which i can create a new database

Comment: i know but my SSMS is unable to connect with database installed at mssql.iserverplanet.com but it is running in vs 2012

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2xsa6y.aspx), you cannot get data without using SSMS.  You can only get the schema.